# How to detect user scrolling MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

This delegate function fires whenever the map's content changes, regardless of whether it's changed in code or whether the user pans or zooms.

```
optional func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView)
```

Is it possible to detect when the user manually pans only?

Comment: Just an idea: when you change in code, save the last region or camera that you set in code. In `mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion` check if `mapView`  has the value that you set in code the last time.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will try it soon.